# "Roteiro" de aprendizagem

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estudo análise e desenvolvimento de sistemas e estou atrás de um estágio, fiz a entrevista e o empregador pediu pra que eu estudasse python, alguém tem alguma recomendação de "caminhos" para aprender python?

**Por exemplo:** Muitos dizem para aprender POO e em seguida ver Django.

**PS:** Python vai ser usado para sistemas Web.

Comment: Victor, conforme a caixa amarela diz, sua pergunta não é cabível neste site, pois sugere respostas baseadas em opinioes, e nao é o objetivo deste site esse tipo de conteudo.

Comment: Cara, essa pergunta foi fechada há 9 meses...

Comment: Por que editou algo tao irrelevante entao? A dica foi com o intuito de que voce editou para que fosse reaberta, se nao é esse seu objetivo, ignore o comentario que a pergunta continuará fechada ou será excluida em breve pelo sistema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fica mais fácil se você já tem alguma noção sobre linguagens de programação (variável, função, objetos, condições etc), no [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python) tem um bom curso online (e gratuito) de Python. Os cursos do [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com) também são bons mas quase todos são pagos (dica, acompanhe-os no Twitter pois as vezes liberam os cursos gratuitamente durante um final de semana, aí dá pra fazer um intensivão).

Especificamente no caso do Django o [tutorial do Django Girls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/pt/) é bem completo e te pode ser basta útil.

Mas independente de tudo, aprender uma linguagem de programação é principalmente praticá-la.